# UILabel with custom font doesn't show custom font in iOs 5 Simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am using a custom font with UILabel. I copied the font to the Supporting files folder, added it to the info.plist, and set the font in viewDidLoad with an IBOutlet. I set the font with `-fontWithName:@"7 Segment" size:77.0`, but when I ran the app, it showed Helvetica 17 as the font. I have triple checked the name of the font, and I added an NSLog to show the name of the font the label was set to, and it showed the correct settings. But, it still showed the wrong font. I am using Xcode 4.2 on OS X Lion, with a tab bar storyboard.
Thanks in advance!
Josh The Geek

**EDIT**
I used the code:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self font]);  
for (NSString *family in [UIFont familyNames]) {  
    for (NSString *font in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:family]) {  
        NSLog(@"%@: %@", family, font);  
        // NSLog(@"%@", font);  
    }  
}
```

to get a list of the fonts, and it showed `7 Segment: 7_Segment`, but when I tried to use the font `7_Segment`, it still only showed Helvetica 17. Once again, I'm out of ideas. Here's a screenshot of it trying to set a font and failing. The background is an image, the orange is the failing font. http://www.evernote.com/shard/s167/sh/a59011cf-7c41-4172-b905-dd38d48591cb/b7a111d2e5096a010eeb5fe03f711df3

**EDIT 2**
I tried setting it to AmericanTypewriter, and it worked, so now I know that I have the name wrong. Would someone please help find the name for the font 7 Segment (2D) from http://www.twyman.org.uk/Fonts/ ? Like I said before, iOs told me both `7 Segment` and `7_Segment`, but neither work.

Comment: I don't remember exactly what I did with mine.  But I ran into similar issue like yours.  What happened was that I typed in the wrong font name.  What I thought was the font name was not the actual font name.  If I remember exactly what I did to figure out the actual font name I will update this.

Comment: How did you add it to the plist? it should be in an array of strings with the key of the array as `Fonts provided by application` and each font should be a string in the format fontname.ttf

Comment: Exactly like that: in Uiappfonts. The font that I'm using is the 2d font from www.twyman.org.uk/fonts/ . I've tried many different things, but still nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once. The filename of the font is not always the name of the font itself. [This blog post](http://kgriff.posterous.com/45359635) helped me.